# Optimizing an SQLite max() query

Tags: performance, sqlite, aggregates

I have a table with some hundred million records, with about 15 different columns. The data is among others speed recordings, with a timestamp, an id on the vehicle that is tracked and a speed recording. A single vehicle can have hundreds of thousands speed recordings, and there is about 40 000 different vehicles.

I want to find the maximum speed recording for each single vehicle.

Just querying:

```
SELECT userid, max(speed) from SpeedReadings group by userid
```

Takes a lot of time, so I want to optimize this. My first notion is to make a index with userid and speed. Does the order of the variables in the query, and the index table matter?

Is there speed difference between those two queries:

```
SELECT userid, max(speed) from SpeedReadings group by userid

SELECT distinct userid, max(speed) from SpeedReadings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to optimize the grouping is to have the data stored in a list that is sorted by the user ID, so that the database does not need to keep all possible results around.
In other words, you need an index where `userid` is the first column.

To speed up the computation further, append the `speed` column to the index to get a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx).

The order of columns in the query does not matter.

There is a speed difference with the query `SELECT distinct userid, max(speed) from SpeedReadings`, but I guess you want to get the correct result, so the difference does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I expect the group by renders the correct result, and not the select distinct.

Comment: By the way, when you mention a covering index, you mean a multi column index with both userid and speed, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in the first part of that sentence.